# Very basic java question, nested for loops

Tags: java, ascii

I'm trying to make a week block of a calendar, when I try and connect the day blocks, they print out vertically not next to each other? I know I have the println statement but I don't think that should be causing the issue as it's inside one of the loops.

code:

```
public class MyCalendar {
    public static final int SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawRow();

    }

    public static void drawRow() {

        for (int week = 1; week <= 7; week++) {
            divide();
            // lines
            for (int col = 1; col <= SIZE / 2; col++) {

                System.out.print("|");
                for (int space = 1; space <= SIZE - 1; space++) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();

            }

        }

    }

    public static void divide() {
        for (int length = 1; length <= 1; length++) {

            for (int top = 1; top <= SIZE; top++) {
                System.out.print("=");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output:

```
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|         
==========
|         
|         
|         
|         
|
```

What I want:

```
======================================================================
|         |         |         |         |         |         |            
|         |         |         |         |         |         |           
|         |         |         |         |         |         |           
|         |         |         |         |         |         |            
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
```

I know this is something basic but i really dont know what im doing wrong.  Its gotta be an issue with the println statement but its nested inside the for loop so im not sure why that would be causing the issues. Thanks

Comment: Look at your method that draws a row, you are printing `|`, then a lot of spaces and then a newline `println()`. Obviously, this causes the next `|` to be on the next line. Instead, you should first finish all the spaces and `|` and do the `println()` afterwards, outside of your loops. And I dont know what you were thinking about the `divide` method but the header has to be printed in one go, so one print with many `=`, thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```java
public static void drawRow() {
    header(SIZE * 7);
    for (int week = 1; week <= 7; week++) {
        // lines
        for (int col = 1; col <= 7; col++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int space = 1; space <= SIZE - 1; space++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void header(int sz) {
    for (int top = 1; top <= sz; top++) {
        System.out.print("=");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

When I run this, I can see the output you have in your question:

```
src : $ java MyCalendar 
======================================================================
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |         
|         |         |         |         |         |         |
```

Answer (score 1):

this much is enough

```
public class MyCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int week = 1; week <= 7; week++) {
            System.out.print("=======");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int week = 1; week <= 7; week++) {
            System.out.println("|       |       |       |       |       |       |");
        }

    }
}
```

output

```
=================================================
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       |       |
```

Comment: why not println instead of \n ?

Comment: Also, `\n` is not platform independent, so might actually result in wrong output depending on the OS (on windows for example).

Comment: @VietDD yes both way same thing happens ;)

Comment: @Zabuzard no as far as java is concerrned be it any platform \n  is new line char in java

Comment: No, `println` takes the correct line separator for the current platform, given by `System.lineSeparator()`. `\n` is incorrect on windows for example. A windows console will likely display this incorrectly (without a new line). Same happens if you for example pipe it to a file and open that in Notepad.exe

Comment: @Zabuzard look at this => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: What should this article tell me? It explains the opposite. Windows expects `\r\n`. Do `java MyCalender > foo.txt` and open `foo.txt` in `notepad.exe`, you will see everything in a single line despite `\n` being used. Hence why `%n` is a thing in `printf`, it takes `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: @Zabuzard I C sorry in windows its `\r\n`. thanks anyways for updating my knowlege. let me udate the answer